# In Android through Rest Full API Login is not working?

Tags: android, mysql

I am new to android I started Login through Restful API but I am facing a problem. After taping the login Button it is not opening up the next page and not fetching the logged user details.

I am using displaying details of logged user another file give a Text box id as (textViewUsername) but its not working.

**LoginAcitivity Code**

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements{
    public static final String LOGIN_URL ="http://email.php?email=%27%27&pass=%27%27";

    public static final String KEY_EMAIL="email";
    public static final String KEY_PASSWORD="password";

    private EditText editTextemail;
    private EditText editTextPassword;
    private Button buttonLogin;

    private String email;
    private String password;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        editTextemail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUsername);
        editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);

        buttonLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin);
        buttonLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private void userLogin() {
        email = editTextemail.getText().toString().trim();
        password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, LOGIN_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    if(response.trim().equals("success")){
                        openProfile();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                }
            }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
            map.put(KEY_EMAIL,email);
            map.put(KEY_PASSWORD,password);
            return map;
        }
    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

private void openProfile(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityUserProfile.class);
    intent.putExtra(KEY_EMAIL, email);
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    userLogin();
   /* if(v == buttonLogin){
        startActivity(new Intent(this,ActivityUserProfile.class));
}*/}}
```

**xml activity_login code**

```
**xml Code for activity_login**
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="LoginActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Enter Email"
    />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editTextUsername" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Enter Password"
    />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editTextPassword" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Login"
    android:id="@+id/buttonLogin" />
```

Comment: Do you have the Internet connection permission(<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
) set in the Manifest file? :P

Comment: Also, what's the error message you see in the Logs?

Comment: @mike I added INTERNET Permission in manifest file and no error log id displayed... after clicking login button it not showing anything !!!

Comment: Your snippet above obviously doesn't have it, but are you sure that LoginActivity implements View.OnClickListener ?

Answer (score 0):

Is it Logging or Login?
Assume Logging for this case you must use:

```
@Override
public void onResponse(String response) {
// Log.e(TAG,response); or Log.v(TAG,response)
    if (response.trim().equals("success")) {
        openProfile();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

and you can check in Android Monitor what response is coming and also check in onErrorListner().

Comment: @Harish mittal if click loin button it not displaying anything, login button is not working...!!

Comment: Check 
@Override
public void OnClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.buttonLogin:
                userLogin();
                break;
        }
    }